# Can knitr::spin() pick up global options?

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

knitr::spin() is a great tool for those that prefer to write code first and text second. I would like to use it to produce documents with little code echoing, but lots of output and text comments. However, every time that I turn off echoing and then add some text, spin() turns echoing back on again.

Is there anyway for spin() to pick up global options from the r script that it is spinning? e.g.one conceptual way could be putting

```
#+ opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

as the first line but it doesn't seem to be recognised by spin(). Is there any way to achieve this?

Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: as when `knit`'ing, just set global options in an initial setup chunk.

So, for example, the following spins up just fine, resulting in output that does not echo any of the supplied code.

```
#+ setup, include=FALSE
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)

#+ aChunk
plot(rnorm(99))

#+ anotherChunk
1:100
```

Answer (score 0):

How would it work to set global options such as path to figures directory from the command line?

I have something like: `Rscript -e "require(knitr)" -e "knitr::spin('script.R')" -e 'knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path="./figs")'`, but it always stores pictures in a newly created folder called *figures*.